# Is there a general way to determine periodicity of a function which is defined using $n$ periodic functions?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Edit: To clarify my question once again:

If we have some periodic functions $p_i(x)$ with periods $P_i$ and another function $f$ with each $p_i$ as an input,
$$f(p_1(x), p_2(x), p_3(x),...,p_k(x))$$
then what is the period of $f$?

Comment: This seem a bit too opended. Could provide more details, and what you have tried?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri I made an edit.

Answer (score 3):

Not absolutely sure, but I think what you're asking is this: if we have some periodic functions $p_i(x)$ with periods $P_i$ and another function $f$ with each $p_i$ as an input,
$$f(p_1(x), p_2(x), p_3(x),...,p_k(x))$$
then what is the period of $f$?

If this is what you are asking, then the period of $f$ should be
$$LCM(P_1,P_2,P_3,...,P_k)$$
This $LCM$ may not always exist. For example, in the comment posed by @SemiClassical, he notes that $\sin x+\sin \pi x$ has no period. That is because the period of $\sin x$ is $2\pi$, which is irrational, and the period of $\sin \pi x$ is $2$, which is rational, so their $LCM$ does not exist.

If this is not your question, please clarify.

Comment: Probably worth noting that such an LCM need not exist. For instance, $\sin x+\sin \pi x$ is not a periodic function.

Comment: That is true. I suppose this is because the period of $\sin x$ is irrational and that of $\sin \pi x$ is not, so they have no LCM.

Comment: More generically, there won't be an LCM unless $P_1/P_2$ is rational.

Comment: Fair enough. Should I add that to my answer as well?

Comment: Note that the period may be lower than this; eg if $p_1(x)=\sin(2x)-\sin(x)$ and $p_2(x)=\sin(x)$, both with period $2\pi$, then $p_1(x)+p_2(x)$ has period $\pi$.

Comment: Perhaps I should limit each $p_i$ to be a *single* periodic function rather than a function applying operators to two or more already periodic functions?

Comment: @Frpzzd Yes, that's what I am asking.